# First negative number row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I find the first row where the negative value starts in Oracle? Below is an example.

```
77
74
67
56
42
24
20
19
-17
-28
-31
-36
```

I would like to read the row -17 and do some operations on that row.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, that came up as a single row. But it is actually one below the other.

Comment: There is no "First" row. database tables are unsorted by nature. 
Unless you have a column to use for `order by`, this simply can't be done in a reliable way. 
For more information, read my blog post entitled [The “Natural order” misconception](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the complete row, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where n < 0
order by n asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If you have another column that specifies the ordering of the rows, then:

```
select t.*
from t
where n < 0
order by <ordering col> asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 1):

To select the maximum negative number you can do:

```
select max(n)
from t
where n < 0
```

Remember that in relational database tables, rows do not have inherent ordering. Therefore, in the absence of an ordering criteria, there's no such a thing as "first row where the negative value starts".

Comment: The reason I am doing this is to stop the subtraction of this column with another as soon as it encounters the first negative value. There is an ordering on a date field as well.Thank you, the above logic worked.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a column for sorting, which defines the order of the rows, it could look like this:

```
with t as (
select 77  a, 1  row_order  from dual union all
select 74  a, 2 row_order from dual union all
select 67  a, 3 row_order from dual union all
select 56  a, 4 row_order from dual union all
select 42  a, 5 row_order from dual union all
select 24  a, 6 row_order from dual union all
select 20  a, 7 row_order from dual union all
select 19  a, 8 row_order from dual union all
select -17 a, 9 row_order from dual union all
select -28 a, 10 row_order from dual union all
select -31 a, 11 row_order from dual union all
select -36 a, 12 row_order from dual
), t1 as (
select a, row_number() over (partition by case when a < 0 then 0 else 1 end order by row_order) rn from t
)
select * from t1 where rn = 1 and a < 0;
```

It's using a window function in order to determine the first rows (here for positive a's and negative a's)
Then it selects the first row encountered that is negative.

Comment: Thank you all very much! All the solutions on this post really helped! Much Appreciated.